# Why does the Socket Server stops working?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am creating a WebSocket for an online game. I have some code that works perfectly, but after a time the server stops the Socket. I don't know what can be wrong and I don't have an error or something. It just stops running.

Does anyone know what can be wrong with this code?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var cookies;

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'hostname',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database',
    port: 3306
});
db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err)
        });

function createCookie(name,value,days, socket) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    socket.handshake.headers['cookie'] = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name, socket) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = socket.handshake.headers['cookie'].split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name, socket) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1, socket);
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        if(readCookie('uid', socket) != null) {
            db.query('SELECT * FROM ww_user_settings WHERE usr_set_id = '+readCookie('uid', socket)+' AND usr_set_setting_id = 23').on('result', function(data){console.log('Message from '+data.usr_set_value+': '+msg);io.emit('chat message', data.usr_set_value+": "+msg);});
        }
        else {
            console.log('Unauthorized message sent.');
            socket.disconnect('unauthorized');
        }
    });
});

http.listen(44444, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:44444');
});
```

As I said, the Socket works. But after a time, even when nothing special happens, the Socket stops running on my Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: Could you give us the socket.io log? io.set('log level', 5); Maybe it'll be more evident what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the server lost the connection with the MySQL Server. By losing it, it will stop working.

Comment: Surely you can test for that? NB you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Yes. I had to use a Database Pool, which reconnect automatically. The server keeps running now.